# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not getting called when row is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 5 custom cells in a table view but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not working for only *one cell*. I have added the cell for the row at the index for that cell in the code.

```
let cell : FileSentCell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fileSend") as! FileSentCell
                let fileUrl = self.getImageURL(forFileName: fileNameString!)
                if(fileUrl == nil){
                    cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fileDownloadWhite")
                }else{
                    cell.downloadStatusIndicator.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "downloadedWhite")
                }
                cell.downloadStatusIndicator.isHidden = false
                cell.downloadingIndicator.alpha = 0.0
                cell.sendFileView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cell.name.text = groupMsg.senderDisplayName
                cell.message.text = groupMsg.message
                cell.time.text =  groupMsg.dateSent!
                cell.fileStatus.text = groupMsg.status
                cell.fileIcon.image = returnImage(fileName:groupMsg.message!)
                cell.sendFileView.tag  = indexPath.row
                cell.sendFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
                cell.sendFileView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                return cell
```

I have made UITableview have a single selection. and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is getting called for all the other reuse cells except for this one cell
Is there a reason or should I change some thing in the cellforat row

My **FileSentCell** class is

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class FileSentCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var sendFileView : UIView!
@IBOutlet var message : ChatLabel!
@IBOutlet var time : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var fileStatus : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var fileIcon : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var downloadStatusIndicator : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var downloadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
}
```

One more thing is if I reduce the width of UIView inside content view and click the row where UIView is not being displayed `didSelectRow` is getting called, So `didSelectRow` is not getting called only when it is clicked on the UIView inside content View

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you set properly the tableView delegate?

Comment: Yes it is working properly for other reuse cells

Comment: Please attach your `FileSentCell` code

Comment: My guess would be that something is covering the table and the last cell doesn't get touch inputs.

Comment: @SanthoshSKashyap try removing this line `cell.sendFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)` only for test and let me know if didSelectedRow is called

Comment: Even after removing cell.sendFileView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture) Same result

Comment: @SanthoshSKashyap keep your addGesture line commented and change true by false in this line `cell.sendFileView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: To narrow down the problem: start removing lines of code from the cell initialisation until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
   cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```